# Is it possible to have scss selector that selects class only if it is last child of other element?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I have layout that is generated dynamically so order of elements could change. Each element that is part of this layout has its own different class. I want to be able to select element of certain class but only if it is last child of its parent to apply styling. If element with different class is last child of its parent, it should not be selected. Is it possible to have this kind of scss selector and achieve this functionality without using javascript?

Example:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">Hello!</div>
  <div class="child2">Hello!</div>
  <div class="child3">Hello!</div>
</div>
```

I want to select element with class child3 only if it is last child of div with class parent.
So if child2 class element is last child of div class parent it is not selected, for example here:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">Hello!</div>
  <div class="child3">Hello!</div>
  <div class="child2">Hello!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and this is the normal CSS behaviour. You can do something like this:

```
.parent .child3:last-child {}
```

This is a rule that selects:

- a `.child3` element inside `.parent`.
- `.child3` element comes as the last, there's no other elements after that including text.

For SCSS, you can do something like this:

```
.parent {
  .child3 {
    &:last-child {
      // Rules.
    }
  }
}
```

**Example Snippet**

```css
.parent .child3:last-child {
  background: #ccf;
}
```

```html
<strong>Trial 1</strong>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">Hello!</div>
  <div class="child2">Hello!</div>
  <div class="child3">Hello!</div>
</div>
<hr />
<strong>Trial 2</strong>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">Hello!</div>
  <div class="child3">Hello!</div>
  <div class="child2">Hello!</div>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0):

You can select elements by their attributes, so something like this would achieve your goal.

```css
.parent div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.parent div:last-of-type[class="child3"] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">Hello!</div>
  <div class="child3">Hello!</div>
  <div class="child2">Hello!</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">Hello!</div>
  <div class="child2">Hello!</div>
  <div class="child3">Hello!</div>
</div>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: I guess the OP has asked, _If element with different class is last child of its parent, it should not be selected._ Your answer will not work for that.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman this answer will do the same as yours

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ohhhh Does `last-of-type` selects only the last child? This is interesting. Let me check. Well, it does, now I am totally confused how this CSS works! LoL. Wait... You make me bang my head!

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman it will select the last element with a specific type and since we only have divs then yes, it will select only the last child

Comment: This is interesting. Let me check. Well, it does, now I am totally confused how this CSS works! LoL. Wait... You make me bang my head!